# using kotlinx serialization inside a gradle plugin that creates a gradle task

Tags: kotlin, gradle-plugin, kotlinx.serialization

I am trying to create a gradle plugin that will generate files (serialized from data classes) from a gradle task that can run in another project.
lets say that the classes that I am serializing are marked with some annotation `@Annot` and I find all the relevant classes with reflection in the gradle task (I made sure to depend on kotlin compile so that the binaries are created). The problem is that when I try to use

```
val clazz: Class<*>
clazz.kotlin.serializer()
```

I get a `Serializer for class 'Type' is not found.` (Type is the actual class that I found and is annotated with `@Serializable` and `@Annot` .
I am using gradle version 7.2, kotlin 1.5.21 (tried with 1.5.31 too)
The project that uses the plugin has a kotlinx serialization plugin enabled
What am I missing? why can’t I access the class serializer with the gradle task?

Note* if I run the above code in the target project (and not in the plugin then the `serializer()` function doesn't throw an exception

Comment: Interesting. I suspect this is related to the fact that `kotlinx.serialization` relies on a compiler plugin to generate the serializers and `serializer()` functionality. I'm guessing at this point in the Gradle execution life cycle that compiler plugin didn't run yet.

Comment: so the plugin runs after the compile runs? do we know if there is a gradle task to run the plugin? just wondering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So This didn't work in a the way I wanted it to but I found a way to make it work.
I defined a task that extends `JavaExec` task:

```
tasks.create(createFilesTaskName, JavaExec::class.java) {
        mainClass.set("package.of.file.SchemaKt")
        classpath = sourceSets.getByName("main").runtimeClasspath
        group = groupName
}
```

The code in `SchemaKt` is in the source set of my kotlin sources or alternatively in a package required by the current project.
The `serializer()` is accessible and working from there and I can run the schemas creation from a gradle task which is exactly what I needed.

I hope this helps someone in the future.